# Android app installs from Android Studio, but not externally as .apk. Throws "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: android, apk, minify, android-app-bundle

Unable to launch Android application when installed externally as .apk. Application installs fine on devices when installed using Android Studio. Logcat shows the error as,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.acme.someprogram, PID: 3806
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain peer field ID for class com.sun.jna.Pointer
   at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
   at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(SourceFile:726)
   at com.sun.jna.Native.r(SourceFile:1)
   at org.vosk.LibVosk.<clinit>(SourceFile)
   at org.vosk.LibVosk.vosk_set_log_level(Native Method)
   at net.acme.someprogram.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:272)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1481)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Gradle app script is,

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.acme.someprogram"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0@aar'
implementation group: 'com.alphacephei', name: 'vosk-android', version: '0.3.32+'
implementation project(':models')
}
```

Specific suggestions and advice regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have significantly changed the verbiage of this question to more accurately reflect the defining symptoms of the problem as I have identified them.

Comment: Verify JNA Usage: The error message references com.sun.jna.Pointer, which indicates the usage of JNA (Java Native Access) library. Make sure you have properly included and configured JNA in your project. Check if the JNA library version is compatible with your app.
Test on Different Devices: Try running your app on multiple Android devices or emulators with different architectures (e.g., ARM, x86) to ensure the issue is not specific to a particular device or architecture.

Comment: Tested on several devices, Android 8.1 through 13. Error is consistent. Previously worked fine when downloaded from Android Play.

Comment: are you building the APK from the android studio or just installing this APK from the play-store ? –

Comment: Actually, the application will install on devices using Android Studio fine. It is when I try and install through Google Play that the problem occurs. I have tried removing the app from the device before install, but I still get the error.

Comment: Install your app from Google Play and then extract the APK files that have been installed to the device. Compare the extracted APKs with the one you get from Android Studio. Do you upload a single APK or an app bundle to Google?

Comment: I've been doing the app bundle for the last few years per their recommendation. Something has changed w/Play. I had a version on Play that up until a short while ago was installing fine on devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled code minifying in Gradle and the issue was solved.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a minification present:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

you shoud add the following lines to the **proguard-rules.pro** file:

```
-keep class com.sun.jna.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.sun.jna.** { *; }
```